Issue with Missing Virtual Environment Prefix and PyQt6-tools Freezing
I am encountering an issue where the command line no longer shows the virtual environment prefix "(venv)" which used to indicate that I am in a virtual environment. Previously, each new line in my terminal would begin with this prefix, but it has stopped appearing.
Additionally, I am working on converting a .ui file to Python using pyqt6-tools, but every time I attempt to load it, the command line freezes at the same point and does not proceed. This issue occurs consistently in the PyCharm terminal, within PyCharm's settings, and in the Windows CMD, all within a virtual environment.
Has anyone experienced similar issues or could provide any insights into why the virtual environment prefix might disappear and why pyqt6-tools might be freezing?
Thank you for any assistance you can provide.
what i have tried
where it all stops
